# How to make responsive design transitions smooth?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm implementing responsive design and my media queries have static rules such as:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
   #content {
      float: none;
      margin-right: 0;
   }
}
```

And so on.

These rules however create jumps and flickers when screen is resized to rule's width . So you go from 810px to 805, then to 800px and then suddenly the design jumps to new media rules.

How do I make my responsive design to jump to new media rules smoothly so that it's a pleasant transition?

I've seen many websites do that but I don't know how they did it so I know that it's certainly possible ... just how?

Answer (score 2):

Add a transition. https://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/

```
#content {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is too broad, here's a good read by google on the subject:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/index?hl=en

https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html#authentic-motion-mass-weight

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the stuff you want to change when max-witdh gets above a specific width.
If you want the padding of a box to grow you can give that box a transition

```
#content{
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    padding: 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #content {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
```

If you want to have two boxes to be displayed next to each other on larger displays and below each other on smaller screens, thats a completely different story. (I'd say you need JavaScript for that too.)

But on the other hand... are you sure you want to animate a transition between different screen sizes? Does that usually change? If it changes is it worth the effort and worth the bigger filesize for your css, js?

Comment: @cocoa, sorry you have been faster.